# What would be the time complexity of multiplying a square matrix $A$ of size $K \times K$, $n$-times?

Tags: matrices, dynamic-programming

I have got O$(k^3 \log(n))$. But I could not justify the time. Could you please elaborate the same? 
In case of Matrix Chain Multiplication all parenthesisations of $A$ $n$-times will have a cost of $(n-1)k^3$.

Comment: Multiplying $A$ by what, itself?  Do you mean computing $A^n$?

Comment: The body of your question should make sense by itself, without the title — much as no book's first sentence is in its title.

Comment: Look [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/complexity-of-computing-matrix-powers) for a related post. It points to a [survey paper](http://www.ccrwest.org/gordon/jalg.pdf).